# Create an iPhone app for personal use without using Xcode or going through the App Store

Tags: ios

I want to make a little app just for me. I don't want to distribute it, and don't want to make any money from it, I just need to have this app with me.

I don't have a Mac capable of running Xcode, and I don't want to waste any money on the developer license.

Is there a way I can make an app for only my personal iPhone 4s, without going through the App Store or using Xcode? My iPhone is jailbroken.

Comment: If the app is simple and you can spend some money, you can get it done on a freelancer site

Answer (score 2):

A web app might be a better solution.

Comment: No, you can build an app with HTML5

Comment: I didn't know that, thank you! With [this](http://sixrevisions.com/web-development/html5-iphone-app/) little tutorial I think I will be able to do it!

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no. You would need a Mac/Xcode to compile/build the application for you. As @Thalecress suggested you might be better off building a web app.

Answer (score 0):

Also check [PhoneGap](http://www.phonegap.com), with it you can deploy your web app in several platforms (including iOS, Android and WP7). Phonegap also offers a build service that you can use to wrap the final web app as a native app to run it on a device ([PhoneGap:Buld](https://build.phonegap.com/)).